# "gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send" - Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Tags: javascript, email, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to send an email using Google's API, and it throws the error

> "gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send" - Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: how bout posting more code? like including the whole function. we don't know what's on your code editor.